# Sorting a sql database alphabetically with links/buttons

Tags: php, html, sql, alphabetical

Hello scripterfriends,

I'm working on a project where I need to sort a row in alphabetical order. After searching for some solutions I didn't find the one I was looking for. Lets say I need only the products that start with the letter "F". I want it like the picture below: https://gyazo.com/488ccc8fd2beaadbc96d687938e5a6ff

I need to be able to click the F and let it only show the product the start with the F.

The code I have so does the trick but I need to change the code in order to get another letter. This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

try {
    $sQuery = "SELECT receptnummer, receptnaam, receptingredient, receptbereidingstijd, receptbereidingswijze, receptcategorie, receptbenodigdheden, receptserveertips, klantnummer
     FROM recept
     WHERE receptnaam LIKE '%f%' ORDER BY receptnaam";

    $oStmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);

    $oStmt->execute();

    if ($oStmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo '<table border="2">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<td>receptnummer</td>';
        echo '<td>receptnaam</td>';
        echo '<td>receptingredient</td>';
        echo '<td>receptbereidingstijd</td>';
        echo '<td>receptbereidingswijze</td>';
        echo '<td>receptcategorie</td>';
        echo '<td>receptbenodigdheden</td>';
        echo '<td>receptserveertips</td>';
        echo '<td>klantnummer</td>';

        while ($aRow = $oStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptnummer'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptnaam'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptingredient'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptbereidingstijd'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptbereidingswijze'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptcategorie'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptbenodigdheden'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['receptserveertips'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $aRow['klantnummer'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'helaas, geen gegevens gevonden';
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $sMsg = '<p>
    Regelnummer: ' . $e->getLine() . '<br/>
    Bestand: ' . $e->getFile() . '<br/>
    Foutmelding: ' . $e->getMessage() . '
</p>';

    trigger_error($sMsg);
}
$db = null;
?>
```

Can someone help me out on this one???

Thanks in advance,

DigitalDentist

Comment: if something begins with "F" remove the first percent sign in `'%f%'`

Comment: yes fred is right %f% means anything in front then a 'f' then anything behind if using like command

Comment: Before clicking a letter, are all of the records already shown client-side?  If so, it seems like filtering client-side would be better since another trip to the server isn't needed.

Comment: But how is it possible to link other variables to a link or a button with that specific letter?

Answer (score 0):

Apply This query

```
 $sQuery="SELECT receptnummer, receptnaam, receptingredient, receptbereidingstijd, receptbereidingswijze, receptcategorie, receptbenodigdheden, receptserveertips, klantnummer
 FROM recept
 WHERE receptnaam LIKE 'f%' ORDER BY receptnaam";
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole trick is inside this query:

```
$sQuery="SELECT receptnummer, receptnaam, receptingredient, receptbereidingstijd, receptbereidingswijze, receptcategorie, receptbenodigdheden, receptserveertips, klantnummer
 FROM recept
 WHERE receptnaam LIKE '%f%' ORDER BY receptnaam";
```

All you need to do is to replace `f` in `LIKE '%f%'` with a variable, which you can get from a POST/GET request.

Edit: as others mentioned, you should probably replace your `%f%` with `f%`, unless you're looking for word that just include, not only start with, the letter f.

Comment: But is there anyway to make the letter "A" show everything with an A and the "B" everthing with a B and so on. Like in a menu like this : " A | B | C | D | ... " ?

Comment: @DigitalDentist I am not sure If I understand you correctly. Do need to show the contents of the whole table sorted in alphabetical order? If so, you'll have to run multiple queries. Make a string `$alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, then put your code in a FOR loop for each character in that string. Do not forget to do `mysqli_next_result($database);` after each query so you can send a new one

Comment: I've figured it out already myself ;) Thanks for the help anyways!